# Error 'float' object has no attribute 'encode' when using apply(unidecode) to a dataframe's column of str

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oop, encode

I'm trying to remove the accents from a dataframe's column using a for loop, but I keep receiving the error message "float object has no attribute encode" and it's an str column. The funniest is that I apply this loop in two points of my code and it's only identifying an error in the second point.

```
df_ = df_target.copy()

for col in df_:
    if col == 'estado' or col == 'cidade' and (df_[col] is not None and isinstance(df_[col], str)):
        print(df_[col].head(100))
        df_[col] = df_[col].apply(unidecode)
```

*df_target* is a pandas dataframe, before this step, it receives the data from a CSV file

*col* reads the column's names from the dataframe

df_[col] should reads all the elements in the columns named *estado* (state) and *cidade* (city)

I just want to remove all the accents from these two columns.

If someone can help me too to write this for loop in list comprehension would be great, I tried but didn't work. This slice is inside of a class and I want to keep cleanest and simplest as possible.

Comment: Without knowing what shape/type `df_target` is (I assume it’s an iterable of string values) and without actually trying the code: `df_ = [col.apply(unicode) for col in df_target if col == 'estado' or col == 'cidade']`. No need for the other tests, methinks. But that comprehension probably won’t address the error you mention, and it operates more like a filter than the actual copy & modify of your code.

Comment: Pandas doesn't have `str` columns, does it?  A column, a pandas Series, might have an object dtype, and contain Python string elements.  Where does the error occur?  in the `unidecode` line?  Could it be that the column also has numbers?  If object dtype it can contain a variety of items, string, `None` or floats.

Comment: Sorry @Jens, I'll edit my question to be more clear. dt_target is a pandas dataframe, this variable reads a CSV file that contains a column of states, one of cities, countries and other about page visualizations. I'm trying to remove accents from the state column and the city column because I have another dataset that does not have the accents in this kind of data and I need to cross relate both. I'll try this comprehension!

Comment: @hpaulj this dataset that I'm working with is large and I don't know if there's another information besides state names or city names, I imagine that can exits some float data but I was hoping filter it with isinstance(). I executed the exact same loop in a jupyter notebook and it does well, but when I pass this to an oop code, I get this error.

Comment: The isinstance test isn't doing anything if the col names are right.

Comment: The type of a dataframe column is `Series`, never `str`.  If it contains strings its `dtype` will be `object`.  `isinstance(df_[col], str)` does not test the type of the elements of that series.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't express myself in the best way possible, I wanted to say that the elements in the column are str. You know a way to remove the non-str elements from the loop? I'm searching but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @Jens I tried this comprehension but it only returns a class list with only two elements, I need to return the entire dataframe but with the two columns I mentioned without accents

Comment: You have two iterations.  One is over the columns of `df`.  `for col in ['estado', 'cidade']:   The other is the `apply`, which acts on the elements of a column.  I think you need to write the `apply` function in a way that distinguishes between string values that can be `unidecode`, and numeric ones that can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, I solved my problem "forcing" all my series elements to str.

```
        for col in df_target:
        if col == 'estado' or col == 'cidade':
            df_target[col] = df_target[col].astype(str)
            df_target[col] = df_target[col].apply(unidecode)
```

I think this wasn't the smarter solution but I was struggling and I opted for this solution cause my deadline was short.

Tks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the operator precedence. 
`or` has higher precedence to `and`.

So putting brackets in the expression might help.

```
if (col == 'estado' or col == 'cidade') and (df_[col] is not None and isinstance(df_[col], str)):
```

secondly. instead of the for loop. define the predicate and pass the predicate to the apply function

```
def pred(x):
    # code

df_.apply(pred, axis=1)
```

Comment: I already try to add brackets in the expression but do not solve my problem, I'll try the second one and let you know if this work. :)